# RSpec: how to write tests with accents?

Tags: testing, rspec, cucumber

I'm new in cucumber and rspec, and I'm trying to test a button whose text is "Regístrate" (look at the accent "í").

In my app, I have a lot of controls written in spanish, with accents á é í ó ú. But I get an error because of these vowels with accents. I'm sure there is an easy solution but I don't achieve to find a solution.

I could change the tests descriptions, but not the words in the user application... any suggestion?

```
describe "signup" do

  before { visit signup_path }

  let(:submit) { "Regístrate" }

  describe "con información válida" do
    it "no debería crear el usuario" do
      expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
    end
  end

  describe "con información válida" do
    before do
      fill_in "Nombre",         with: "Example User"
      fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
      fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
      fill_in "Confirmación", with: "foobar"
    end

    it "debería crear el usuario" do
      expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

error:

```
user_signup_steps.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
"Regístrate"
   ^ (SyntaxError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an encoding error. Try adding this line to the top of the spec file:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```